# Rotate View by Using Core Motion on Device Rotate

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I am new to CoreMotion API. I want to rotate my view on device rotation where view will rotating based on speed, velocity. Speed and Velocity getting from device rotation. Device will be on flat horizontal surface. So rotation should be considering only Z-Axis.

I uploaded screen shot of view to rotate. The orange colour view for rotation.

Give me right direction.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add coreMotion Framework to your project and use cadence

```
import UIKit

import CoreMotion;

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    guard CMPedometer.isCadenceAvailable()   else{
        print("cadence data is not available")
        return
    }
    let oneWeekAgo = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -(7 * 24 * 60 * 60))
    CMPedometer().startUpdates(from: oneWeekAgo)
    {
        data, error in

        guard let pData = data, error == nil
        else
        {
            return
        }

        if let cadence = pData.currentCadence
        {
            print("current Speed = \(1.0/cadence.doubleValue)")
        }

    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: @Sh_Khan, This answer is not useful for me, As per apple documentation I read that, CMPedometer is an object for fetching the system-generated live walking data. But I want to know about rotation of device. Suppose to I put device on flat horizontal surface and manually rotate it on Z-Axis. So it there will be 0 angle between device and surface. I can’t find any solution.

Comment: I understood what you need is that like a compass app  ??

Comment: I will edit the answer for it but only in objective c as I don't have time to convert it give me 5 minutes